# Drag and Drop events in QGraphicsLayoutItem

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I'm trying to build a group of GraphicItems that I can move in the layout and switch positions of them. The problem that I'm having is that the drag events are not triggered in the child items.
I've been searching and some other topics suggested to create a custom Scene overriding the events.

I set the setAcceptDrops in the child methods and also set this flags: *QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable | QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges*
with no luck.

Find below my example:

```
from PySide6 import QtCore
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *


class CustomRect(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomRect, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setRect(0.0, 0.0, 80.0, 80.0)


class MyProxy(QGraphicsProxyWidget):
    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        e.acceptProposedAction()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        # pass drop event to child widget
        return self.widget().dropEvent(e)

    def dragMoveEvent(self, e):
        e.acceptProposedAction()


class RectGroup(QGraphicsItemGroup):
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super(RectGroup, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setHandlesChildEvents(False)
        self.addToGroup(CustomRect())
        label = QLabel(text)
        self.proxy = MyProxy()
        self.proxy.setHandlesChildEvents(False)
        self.proxy.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.proxy.setWidget(label)
        self.proxy.setPos(30, 30)
        self.addToGroup(self.proxy)

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()


class Item(QGraphicsLayoutItem):
    def __init__(self, graphics_group, parent=None):
        super(Item, self).__init__(parent)
        self.gg = graphics_group

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()

    def sizeHint(self, *args, **kwargs):
        boundingrec = self.gg.boundingRect()
        r = QtCore.QSizeF()
        r.setHeight(boundingrec.height())
        r.setWidth(boundingrec.width())
        return r

    def setGeometry(self, x):
        self.gg.setPos(x.topLeft())


class Container(QGraphicsWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Container, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.layout = QGraphicsGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def add_item(self, item, row, col):
        self.layout.addItem(item, row, col)


class MyScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        e.acceptProposedAction()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        # find item at these coordinates
        item = self.itemAt(e.scenePos())
        if item.setAcceptDrops == True:
            # pass on event to item at the coordinates
            try:
                item.dropEvent(e)
            except RuntimeError:
                pass  # This will supress a Runtime Error generated when dropping into a widget with no MyProxy

    def dragMoveEvent(self, e):
        e.acceptProposedAction()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        central_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(central_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.resize(500, 500)

        view = QGraphicsView()
        scene = MyScene()
        view.setScene(scene)

        container = Container()
        scene.addItem(container)
        for i in range(3):
            rg = RectGroup(f"foo_{i}", container)
            rg.setFlags(
                QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable | QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges)
            rg.setAcceptDrops(True)
            f = Item(rg)
            container.add_item(f, i, 0)
        central_layout.addWidget(view)


app = QApplication([])
main = MainWindow()
main.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: If you check the [QGraphicsLayoutItem documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicslayoutitem.html) you'll see that it's an abstract class that does **not** inherit from QGraphicsItem. It is a *layout element*, not a graphic one, and, just like a standard Qt layout (QLayoutItem), it will **never** receive any user event.

Comment: Great, thanks for your answer. Then how can I implement drag&drop in the QGraphicsItemGroup ?? it's not triggering neither

Comment: I'm afraid that you're confusing the *movable* capability of an item with the *actual* drag&drop functionality. I suggest you to carefully read the main [Drag and Drop](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/dnd.html) guide and the [related chapter](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/graphicsview.html#drag-and-drop) for the graphics view framework. Also, read more carefully the QGraphicsItem documentation, as setting the `ItemSendsGeometryChanges` does nothing on its own: you have to override [`itemChange()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#itemChange) in order to detect all geometry related `GraphicsItemChange` flags.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).